# In an inner product space X, if ||λx + (1-λ)y|| = ||x|| for all λ ∈ [0, 1] then x = y

Tags: convex-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

I tried to prove that, in an inner product space $X$, if $\|λx+(1-λ)y\|$ = $\|x\|$ for all $λ$ $∈$ $[0, 1]$ and for $x$ and $y$ from $X$, then $x$ $=$ $y$.

Is it correct to plugin particular value of $λ$ to get the result? Or is there any simple way to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(\lambda) = {1 \over 2} \|\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y \|^2$. Since $f$ is constant for $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we must have
$f'(\lambda) = 0$ for $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Note that $f'(\lambda) = \lambda \|x-y\|^2 -\|y\|^2 + \langle y, x \rangle$.

It follows that $\|x-y\| = 0$ or equivalently, $x=y$.

Comment: How can we claim that f(λ) is constant?

Comment: If $f(\lambda) = {1 \over 2} \|x\|^2$ for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$ then it must be a constant. This was the assumption in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Square both sides to get
$$\lambda^2 \|x-y\|^2 + \|y\|^2 + \lambda \langle x-y, y\rangle = \|x\|^2$$
for all $\lambda \in [0,1]$.
Taking $\lambda = 0$ in the original condition shows that $\|x\|=\|y\|$, so two terms above can be canceled.
Thus for all $\lambda > 0$ we have
$$\lambda \|x-y\| = \langle y - x, y\rangle.$$

Comment: How does this helps to lead us to desired result?

Comment: @Msubedi The last line needs to hold for all $\lambda \in (0,1]$. Here, $\|x-y\|$ and $\langle y-x, y\rangle$ are some fixed numbers. How is this possible? Is it possible for the equation $\lambda \cdot 3 = -2$ to be true for all $\lambda \in (0,1]$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\lambda = 0, {1\over2}$

$\|y\|=\|{x+y\over 2}\|=\|x\|$

$\|{x+y\over 2}\|=\sqrt{{\|x\|^2\over4}+{\|y\|^2\over4}+{\langle x,y\rangle\over2}}=\sqrt{{\|x\|^2\over2}+{\langle x,y\rangle\over2}}\leq \|x\|$ with equality if and only if $x=y$